# CSS with nested divs applies style to all children

Tags: html, css

I am trying to style a div nested inside another so that the links in the inner div are black, instead of the outer div's specified style that links are blue. Here's some simplified HTML to demonstrate, and it should be noted that the first div always has the id, and the inner div a class:

```css
#document.blackLinks a,
.blackLinks a {
  color: #000000;
}
#document a {
  color: #0000FF;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="document">
    <div class="blackLinks">
      <a href="google.com">Black Link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: put space after `#document`

Comment: `#document.blackLinks` matches nothing in your document, and `.blackLinks a` has less _specificity_ (if that doesn’t mean anything to you, go look it up) than the selector `#document a` – so the latter “wins.”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rule `#document.blackLinks a` matches the links that are inside an element with id ***document*** and (*the same element also having*) a class of ***blackLinks***.

You need to put a space between them `#document .blackLinks a` which means, `a` tags inside an element with class ***blackLinks*** which in turn is inside another element with id ***document***

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, that makes perfect sense.